# Randomly getting ora-01017

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, logins, rac

I have an Oracle RAC (12.1.0.2) installed on ESXi 6.5. RAC nodes are hosted on different physical servers and there is a storage hosting their shared disk.

Here is my problem:
Trying on Toad, SQL*Plus, Weblogic Creating data source does not matter... On every method,  Oracle gives ORA-01017 error almost 50% of my tries.

I can't run my software, UIs, services, etc. since I usually fail establishing a connection.

I suspect entropy value but I really dont know what to modify.

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail generally outputs around 3000
```

Please find my samples of connection to SQL*Plus:

```
[oracle@buscordb-nd01 ~]$ sqlplus testuser/testpassword@buscordb

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Jan 20 23:10:47 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Mon Jan 20 2020 23:10:28 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c ...

SQL> exit
Disconnected from ... 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production


[oracle@buscordb-nd01 ~]$ sqlplus testuser/testpassword@buscordb

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Jan 20 23:10:50 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Mon Jan 20 2020 23:10:47 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c ..

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle...


[oracle@buscordb-nd01 ~]$ sqlplus testuser/testpassword@buscordb

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Jan 20 23:10:56 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

As you can see, I get this error with same user (on the database node itself, it is not event a remote machine).

Waiting your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Low entropy causes the connection attempts to take longer instead of failing with invalid/username password. What you described here sounds like you have 2 different databases but they both use the same service name, and depending on where the listener forwards the request, you get in or get an error. This is quite easy to check by checking the TNS entry and the status of listener services.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Remember that there is a RAC configuration installed.  so, there is a single database which has two nodes. Beside that, for instance, when I try on weblogic, I always test on both node by giving their ip addresses instead of a scan_name. what I mean is that on each node I get this random error. According to crsctl command, listeners shared among nodes.  But I will check and compara TNS entries.

Comment: Sounds very similar to the issue reported here: https://blog.dbi-services.com/random-ora-01017-invalid-usernamepassword-in-12cr2/